# Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found JBoss 7.1.2

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jboss7.x

I'm trying to consume a WebService from JBosss 7.1.2.
But I get a Caused by:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
```

I tried to add the following dependencies to my MANIFEST.MF:

```
Dependencies: org.jboss.xts, org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client services export
```

But this doesn't take any effect. I also tried to add  the dependencies to my jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
I know that the jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar contains the ProviderImpl class. But I don't how to tell JBoss where to find these JAR.
Do you know what I have to do for solving this problem?