# JBoss : Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I’m fairly new to JBoss and I have a problem regarding .rar deployment. I don’t have any deep going knowledge about deployment and JBoss-architecture, so I’m going to try to write down all I know and everything that maybe be relevant.

We are developing a web service connector for a JBoss in a third party domain. I have an SDK from the third party company which uses jca (as far as I know). I inherited from a class that is called `AbstractRAManagedConenction`, which implements `ManagedConnection` from package `javax.resource.spi`. Also I have a class which inherits `AbstractResourceManagedConnectionFactory` which implements `ManagedConnectionFactory` from the same package.
I also have a class, which will contain the business logic for connecting to our ECM-system. This class is instantiated in the constructor by the inherited `AbstactRAManagedConnection`.

So far so good (I think). Now comes the problematic part.
In the constructor of the business logic class, I connect to a soap endpoint using Jax-Ws (automatically generated by NetBeans 8.1) this section fails in deployment with an exception that states `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found`.

The .rar Archive looks like this:

```
-notxLZAStorageenaio-service-ds.xml
-META-INF
    -ironjacamar.xml
    -jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    -MANIFEST.MF
    -ra.xml
-lib
    -storagejca-common.jar
    -rt.jar
    -two third party jar’s
    -our jar
```

Our jar looks like this:

```
-de (containing business logic)
-ietf (containing auto generated code)
-iso (containing auto generated code)
-META-INF
    -wsdl
        -(definitions of soap service)
    -jax-ws-catalog.xml
    -MANIFEST.MF
-oasis (containing auto generated code)
-org (containing auto generated code)
```

I tried the following to get rid of this exception:

- added `jaxws-rt.jar` in `lib` directory
- added `Class-Path: lib/jaxws-rt.jar` entry in `MANIFEST.MF` of .rar
- added `Class-Path: lib/jaxws-rt.jar` entry in `MANIFEST.MF` of our jar
- added `rt.jar` in `lib` directory
- added `Class-Path: lib/rt.jar` entry in `MANIFEST.MF` of .rar
- added `Class-Path: lib/rt.jar` entry in `MANIFEST.MF` of our jar

After that, I tried to use jboss-deployment-structure.xml to pass the dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
        <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="com/sun/xml/internal/ws/spi"/>
                </paths>
            </system>       
        [module from third party]
            <module name="com.sun.xml.ws.api" export="true" />
            <module name="com.sun.xml.ws.rt" services="import"/>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

As this didn’t worked either, I added a folder structure to the jboss modules directory and copied rt.jar in it with a module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="de.osvh.test">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="rt.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

I then added `<module name="de.osvh.test" export="true"/>` to the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.
That all did not work, and the exception is still the same.

So… this took me around 3-4 days, as I am totally new to Jboss. I have no clue what to try else, so this is kind of my last resort.
If you need any more information, please let me know and describe how to retrieve it, I then try to achieve that and post it here.
Many thanks in advance!

P.S.: There is a unanswered question regarding this topic:
[Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found JBoss 7.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630470/caused-by-javax-xml-ws-webserviceexception-provider-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-sp)

**Solved:**
An update of the surrounding JBoss did the trick. The JavaEE did not include the needed package (at least thats what they are saying). There was nothing wrong with my deployment.

Comment: While I don't know JBoss and can't really help you with this particular question, please throw a glance at the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for future questions. A easy-to-read question attracts more (and better) possible responses. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm.... I´ve the same problem - on a keycloak 8.0.1 - which is basically wildfly 10. Tried everything. I just want to call a simple SOAP webservice... can´t be that complcated.
Tried JVM 11, JVM 8, jboss-deployment-structure.xml with exporting the internal package... nothing worked so far